# Python split + rename

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to python and need some help adapting this code to my samples. It's supposed to take multiple bed files that end with: ".regions.bed", and subsequently convert these to .csv. That part is fine, however I don't understand the whole split thing, specifically from: file.split('_')[2] == "AA": and the code below that. Could anyone please explain what this code does to the files?

```
out_coverage = pd.DataFrame()

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):      
    for file in files:
        
        if file.endswith(".regions.bed"):
            #file = f[0:len(f)-12]
            
            if file.split('_')[2] == "AA":
                
                r = "GX_" + file.split('_')[3]
                run = r[0:len(r)-12]
                sample = file.split('_')[0] + "_" + file.split('_')[1]
                
                
            else:
         
                r = "AA_" + file.split('_')[2]
                run = r[0:len(r)-12]
                sample = file.split('_')[0]
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question: `r[0:len(r)-12]` is an unnecessarily complicated way of writing `r[:-12]`.

Comment: The file.split('\_') create a list of strings, for example: the string s = 'a_b_c_d.png'. If you apply s.split('\_'), you will get as a return ['a','b','c','d.png']. And if you do s.split('\_')[2] you just get as a return 'c', which is the element corresponding in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice thing about python is that you can try out things interactively:

```
$ python
Python 3.9.10 (main, Jan 20 2022, 22:28:26)
>>> file = "just_some_simple_test.regions.bed"
>>> file
'just_some_simple_test.regions.bed'
>>> file.endswith(".regions.bed")
True
>>> file.split('_')
['just', 'some', 'simple', 'test.regions.bed']
>>> file.split('_')[2]
'simple'
>>> file.split('_')[2] == "AA"
False
>>> file[:-12]
'just_some_simple_test'
>>> file[:-12].split('_')
['just', 'some', 'simple', 'test']
```

So, as you can see, `file.split('_')` splits the string contained in file at each `_`-character and creates a list with the segments. `[2]` chooses the third (0 is the first) element from that list and `== "AA"` compares this with `AA`.